# Smart POJO convertion in java

Tags: java, spring, mapping, objectmapper

Are there any libraries or, even better, Springframework utilities, allowing smart bidirectional mapping A <-> B without writing mappers manually?

```
class A {
   private String xProp1;
   private String xProp2;  
   private String yProp3;
   private String yProp4;
}

class B {
   private X x;
   private Y y;

   static class X {
      private String prop1;
      private String prop2;
   }
   static class Y {
      private String prop3;
      private String prop4;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are quite a few: [Orika](https://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/index.html), [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/), [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/), [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) and probably many others.

Comment: I would remove Dozer from the list as the others are more efficient. (you can also add Selma)